# Strange error creating variable in Stata?

Tags: stata

I can't figure out how this is possibly happening in Stata.  The data are integers with no missing values.

```
gen aid=bid*10000+cid
gen temp=0
replace temp=1 if aid!=bid*10000+cid
sum temp
```

The mean of `temp`  equals 0.27, and I can see many places where the variable `aid` is not coded according to the formula.  How is this possible?  I have tried running it in Stata 12 and 13 and got the same results. In every case with an error `aid` is off by 1 or 2 in the ones digit.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
set obs 1

gen wid=2107 
gen fid=2104 

gen mid=fid*10000+wid 
di mid
```

Comment: Looks like a precision issue but you don't give away enough information. Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: See `help data types` and `help float`.

Comment: Here is a reproducible example:  `gen wid=2107`

`gen fid=2104`

`gen mid=fid*10000+wid`

`di mid`
21042108

Comment: This doesn't seem like a precision issue to me.  The numbers are only 8 digits, and they differ in the ones digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example:

```
clear 
set more off

set obs 1

gen wid=2107 
gen fid=2104 

gen mid = fid*10000 + wid 
gen double mid2 = fid*10000 + wid 

display mid
display mid2
```

The default data type is a *float* and "floats have about 7 digits of accuracy".

If you increase the precision of your data type, you see the expected. Read the references I gave in previous comments: `help data types` and references within.

Comment: Thanks for the fix!  I wonder how many times I have gotten the wrong answer without even knowing.  I never realized that adding integers was so difficult.

Comment: The good news is that often such details make little difference to practical results. After all, you could use `double`s rather than `float`s for measured variables too, but you'd often not notice any scientific consequences. But strange errors can occur if large integers are used as identifiers, which appears to be what you are doing here. Identifiers are often better held as strings.